# Static electricity on my PC, and crash on USB key touch

Tags: esd

My PC is a bit weird:  Sometimes, I can switch it on just by touching the front side near the power button.  Very fun in fact, I love it!

But sometimes, when I connect a USB key, the PC just crashes.  In fact, I just have to touch the USB port with the key to crash it.  I think there is a little problem of static electricity and maybe a small electric leak.

Do you think I am right?  I am a software developer, not an electronics guru.  How can I figure out what is going on, and how I can correct this?

The PC runs Ubuntu Linux, but I am not sure this is related.

Comment: If touching the case induceses a change in state of the power, there must be a pretty severe grounding problem.  I don't recommend even touching that one for risk of shock.  Consider buying a new case or a new computer because odds are the hardware has already taken damage from static which can produce latent problems that are difficult to pinpoint (ruin RAM, motherboard, CPU, basically entire thing).

Comment: (This web site needs "humour" votes -- this post definitely deserves a few because of the "very fun in fact, I love it" comment!)

Comment: Do you have grounded outlets? In case you don't have: http://www.handymanusa.com/articles/ground1.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your AC likely isn't grounded properly.  You may need to get an electrician to check your wiring (or you can buy a $10 simple AC circuit tester and plug it in to see if things are wired correctly -- if ground is missing, then the three lights will indicate that immediately).

[image: simple AC circuit tester]

Comment: +1 great answer. @Cédric Girard
 Once you get the issue of grounding resolved, I recommend running memtest x86 to test the components for failure due to static.  http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: In addition to the excellent suggestion to run a memory test, vacuuming out any dust can be helpful too since dust can also carry static electricity.